# How to change state on ui-router persisting stateParams?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ui-sref

I'm using ui-router in angularjs, and I have the following code:

in `blog.module.js`

```
$stateProvider
    .state('blog', {
        url: '/domains/:domain_id/blog',
        template: '<ui-view></ui-view>',
        title: 'Blog',
    })
    .state('blog.posts', {
        url: '/posts',
        template: 'Hello world',
        title: 'Posts',
    });
```

and `modules.module.js`

```
$stateProvider
    .state('modules', {
        url: '/domains/:domain_id/modules',
        templateUrl: '/assets/templates/modules/index.tpl.html',
        controller: 'ModulesCtrl as index',
        title: 'Módulos',
    });
```

The `:domain_id` of all routes make reference to the same thing in my app. But I need/want, if it's possible, to make this `:domain_id` persist on all state change without need to pass it on each `ui-sref` that I use. 
I have no idea how to make this, anyone knows this?

Really thank you for your attention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to set state params whenever you change the state.Because stateParams are within state scope.when state is changed scope of new state is defined. `$state.go('blog.posts',{'domain_id':$stateParams.domain_id});`